# Show that if $A\in S_n^{++}(\Bbb R)$ and $B \in A_n(\Bbb R)$ therefore $AB$ is diagonalizable in $\Bbb M_n(\Bbb C)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Let $S_n^{++}(\Bbb R)$ be the set of positive definite symmetric matrices with real coefficients, $A_n(\Bbb R)$ the set of skew-symmetric matrices with real coefficients. Show that if $A\in S_n^{++}(\Bbb R)$ and $B \in A_n(\Bbb R)$ therefore $AB$ is diagonalizable in $\Bbb M_n(\Bbb C)$.

If $AB=BA$ I know how to get the result. But I'm stuck if $AB \neq BA$... Does someone have a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: prove that $AB$ is similar to a skew-symmetric matrix with real coefficients.

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I ask how you came up with this idea? Do you have any references that may help me see this as something "natural"?

Comment: @Michelle It's gut feeling, but it is also natural to consider what diagonalisable matrices $AB$ is similar to.

Comment: @Michelle Another bit of intuition: whenever a positive definite matrix is involved, it is helpful to ask "is there anything that I can do with $A^{1/2}$?"